# SignalR target a specific user from server with custom IUserIdProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I've an application using SignalR & WebAPI. I've a custom Authorization context based on a token, which I give on each SignalR requests using the QueryString.

I've implement and `IUserIdProvider`, in order to retrieve my User from the Token.

And finally, I want to call a client method from the server, for a specific User (with is ID), I'm using a HubContext from the `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager`.

My problem is that my User is never find from my HubContext, but it is from the Hub itself...

Here is my IUserIdProvider implementation

```
public class SignalRUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
        var token = request.QueryString["token"];
        var scope = GetUnprotectedScope(token);

        if (scope == null)
            return null;

        return scope.Id_User.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is my Hub imlementation

```
[HubName("notifier")]
public class NotifierHub : Hub
{
    public void Notify(string message)
    {
        Clients.User("1").Notify(message); //When call from a client, this works very well, only the User with the Id = 1 receive the notification
    }
}
```

And finally, I use this to call the client method from my server:

```
GlobalHost
    .ConnectionManager
    .GetHubContext<NotifierHub>()
    .Clients
    .User("1")
    .Notify(notification.Message);
    // This does nothing...
```

I'm out of solution at this point, I don't understand what happens, does anyone have already achieve this ?

Comment: What happens when you debug the `GetUserId` method? Is `Scope` null?

Comment: Everything if fine in my SignalRUserIdProvider, i've always my Token in the QueryString, and my Id_User in the Scope. It's in the call from GlobalHost.ConnectionManager where the User is not found and the notification never sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured the issue, but I don't know how to fix it...

The actual issue is simple, the `Hub` itself has a good context with the clients and everything, but the `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager` have nothing.

If I change my Hub to something like this:

```
[HubName("notifier")]
public class NotifierHub : Hub
{
    public void Notify(string message)
    {
        Clients.User("1").Notify(message + " from Hub itself");

        GlobalHost
            .ConnectionManager
            .GetHubContext<NotifierHub>()
            .Clients
            .User("1")
            .Notify(message + " from ConnectionManager");
    }
}
```

My client receive "My message from Hub itself", but never receive "My message from ConnectionManager".

In conclusion, I've a problem with my DependencyInjection... I'm using Structuremap, with this DependencyResover :

```
public class StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    private IContainer _container;

    public StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == null)
            return null;

        var service = _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType) ?? base.GetService(serviceType);
        if (service != null) return service;

        return (!serviceType.IsAbstract && !serviceType.IsInterface && serviceType.IsClass)
            ? _container.GetInstance(serviceType)
            : _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        var objects = _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType).Cast<object>();
        return objects.Concat(base.GetServices(serviceType));
    }
}
```

My Startup file:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Map("/signalr", RegisterSignalR);
}

public static void RegisterSignalR(IAppBuilder map)
{
   var resolver = new StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver(IoC.Initialize());
   var config = new HubConfiguration { Resolver = resolver };

   map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
   map.RunSignalR(config);
}
```

And finally my Registry...

```
For<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>().Add<StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver>();

For<INotifier>().Use<SignalRNotifier>();
```

Comment: Why is it  `Notify(notification.Message + " from ConnectionManager")`   and not   `Notify(message + " from ConnectionManager")`